# Is there a way to retrieve all the tags of any tumblr post for my html custom theme?

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I am customizing a tumblr theme and I would like to know whether it is possible to retrieve all the tags of a post and use them as classes for my page container.
So far, I have been able to achieve grabbing post tags in posts that just have one tag, using the following code:

`<div id="page" {block:posts}{block:HasTags}{block:Tags}class={Tag}{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}{/block:Posts}>`

But in those posts that have more than one tag, the above code only grabs the first tag.
So, I was wondering if there's a way, perhaps adding some script to the head, that grabs all the post tags and allows the page to have several classes.
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a neat block that can accomplish this for you called `{TagsAsClasses}`

Just change your code to this:

```
<div id="page" class={TagsAsClasses}>
```

Or if you want to concatenate strings use something like:

```
<div id="page" class="customClass {TagsAsClasses}">
```

The `{block:HasTags}` is expecting to iterate over a block of html (like an anchor) and then output each tag link and tag name in the block, you cannot do that inside a classname selector. Luckily Tumblr provides this function to iterate over the array of tags and separate them with spaces inside the element attribute values.

See this answer for more information: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/27983

Comment: Excellent, thanks.